# What is the correct approach to pass HttpMessageHandler in HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I want to pass `HttpMessageHandler` into my `HttpClient`. The main reason is to pass the proxy (`IWebProxy`).

Ideally, `HttpClient` is defined in constructor like this (Using DI):

```
public class MyApiClient : IMyApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyApiClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        // I am not sure how to pass `handler` here.
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

The way I am adding proxy into `HttpClient` is as following (Not using DI):

```
public class MyApiClient : IMyApiClient {
  private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

  public MyApiClient() {
    var proxy = new WebProxy {
      Address = new Uri("http://test.com:1234"),
      BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
      UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    };

    // Create a client handler that uses the proxy
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
      Proxy = proxy,
    };

    // Disable SSL verification
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
    
    _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is my approach correct to pass proxy?
2. Is it possible to pass proxy in `HttpClient` using DI (first approach)?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Answer to 1: No, it is considered a bad practice for multiple reasons. Answer to 2: Yes. Check my answer and see if that helps you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually handling either `HttpClient` or the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` is considered a bad practice in general due to the way the low level socket resources are managed: in most cases, it would either lead to socket starvation due to leaks, or it could lead to unusable failed connections.

Instead, you should rely on `IHttpClientFactory` and related abstractions. First, I'd strongly recommend reading the guidelines from Microsoft themselves here:

- [IHttpClientFactory with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

The simplest possible way to configure a single handler is to use the `AddHttpClient` overload. In your case, it would look something like the following:

```cs
services
    .AddHttpClient<IMyApiClient, MyApiClient>((provider, client) => 
    {
        // Confiure one-off settings of the client here. 
        // There is an overload which doesn't pass the 'provider', in case
        // you don't need DI during the configuration.
        //
        // For example (using recommended 'IOptions' approach):

        var settings = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyApiSettings>>();
        client.BaseAddress = settings.Value.ApiRoot;
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        // Add whatever logic to create the handler here
        // Similar to the other method, this also has DI-enabled overloads.
        var proxy = new WebProxy 
        {
            Address = new Uri("http://test.com:1234"),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        };

        // Create a client handler that uses the proxy
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy };

        // Disable SSL verification
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        
        return httpClientHandler;
    });
```

This will automatically link the configured `HttpClient` instance with your `MyApiClient` in the container, so that you can then directly inject `HttpClient` in the `MyApiClient` constructor like in your first example:

```cs
public class MyApiClient : IMyApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyApiClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        // It will work now ;)
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. This works as expected.